# QTreeView, QAbstractItemModel. App exits while expanding node

Tags: python, pyqt

I need to display the hierarchical model. Child nodes must be created when user expands the node. The number of child nodes is not known in advance. Some child nodes can be created immediately after expanding parent node. And some child nodes need time to get data by sending request and only then can be created.

So I create QTreeView + QSortFilterProxyModel + Qt model (QAbstractItemModel inheritor) + data model. The code below works fine with the proxy model. But without proxy model + for nodes that created immediately I have `Process finished with exit code -1073741819 (0xC0000005)` while expanding any node. I'm afraid that this error will also appear in the presence of a proxy model sooner or later.

UPD 1: I added the _populate_request signal with QueuedConnection to 'separate' fetchMore call stack from adding/removing nodes from model (thanks to @musicamante - it's the same idea as a single shot timer). That helped. But this step is not obvious for me and I still open for ideas why direct calls leads to crash.

UPD 2: Added "Reload" context menu to reload children. To check old child nodes removing for crash.

```
import random
import sys
import weakref
from enum import Enum, auto
from typing import Optional, List
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtTest
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QMainWindow, QTreeView, QVBoxLayout, QApplication, QMenu
from PyQt5.QtCore import QModelIndex, Qt


class TreeNodeStatus(Enum):
    NotPopulated = auto()
    Populating = auto()
    Populated = auto()
    Error = auto()


class TreeNode(QtCore.QObject):
    """ Node of objects tree; root node is essentially a data model """

    status_changed = QtCore.pyqtSignal(object)  # node
    before_children_added = QtCore.pyqtSignal(object, int, int)  # parent_node, pos, count
    children_added = QtCore.pyqtSignal(object, int, int)  # parent_node, pos, count
    before_children_removed = QtCore.pyqtSignal(object, int, int)  # parent_node, pos, count
    children_removed = QtCore.pyqtSignal(object, int, int)  # parent_node, pos, count

    _populate_request = QtCore.pyqtSignal()

    def __init__(self, name: str, parent: Optional['TreeNode']):
        super().__init__()

        self._name = name

        self._parent_ref = weakref.ref(parent) if parent is not None else lambda: None

        self._status: TreeNodeStatus = TreeNodeStatus.NotPopulated

        self._children: List[TreeNode] = []

        # to listen root node signals only
        if parent is not None:
            self.status_changed.connect(parent.status_changed)
            self.before_children_added.connect(parent.before_children_added)
            self.children_added.connect(parent.children_added)
            self.before_children_removed.connect(parent.before_children_removed)
            self.children_removed.connect(parent.children_removed)

        # to imitate minimal delay between fetchMore > populate call stack and adding/removing nodes;
        # for nodes that can be created immediately in populate direct calls
        # fetchMore > populate > _on_children_received causes crash;
        # using of this signal prevents crash
        self._populate_request.connect(self._populate, Qt.ConnectionType.QueuedConnection)

        # for nodes that can not be created immediately in populate;
        # to imitate delay due to getting response to a request
        self._timer = QtCore.QTimer()
        self._timer.setSingleShot(True)
        self._timer.setInterval(2 * 1000)  # 2s
        self._timer.timeout.connect(self._on_children_received)

    def parent(self) -> Optional['TreeNode']:
        return self._parent_ref()

    @property
    def status(self) -> TreeNodeStatus:
        return self._status

    def _set_status(self, status: TreeNodeStatus):
        self._status = status
        self.status_changed.emit(self)

    def populate(self):
        # # signal with QueuedConnection - works good
        # self._populate_request.emit()
        # direct call causes app crash for nodes that can be created immediately and if there is no proxy model
        self._populate()

    def _populate(self):

        # loading was started for this node already, exit
        if self.status == TreeNodeStatus.Populating:
            return

        # start loading
        self._set_status(TreeNodeStatus.Populating)

        # forget old children
        old_children_count = len(self._children)
        self.before_children_removed.emit(self, 0, old_children_count)
        # disconnect signals
        for child in self._children:
            child.status_changed.disconnect(self.status_changed)
            child.before_children_added.disconnect(self.before_children_added)
            child.children_added.disconnect(self.children_added)
            child.before_children_removed.disconnect(self.before_children_removed)
            child.children_removed.disconnect(self.children_removed)
        self._children.clear()
        self.children_removed.emit(self, 0, old_children_count)

        # request data about children nodes
        # # timer - for nodes that can not be created immediately
        # self._timer.start()
        # direct call - for nodes that can be created immediately
        self._on_children_received()

    def children(self) -> List['TreeNode']:
        return self._children

    @property
    def name(self) -> str:
        return self._name

    def _on_children_received(self):
        print('!_on_children_received', self.name)

        # create children nodes
        new_children_count = random.randint(0, 4)
        self.before_children_added.emit(self, 0, new_children_count)
        self._children = [TreeNode(self.name + ' ' + str(i), self) for i in range(new_children_count)]
        self.children_added.emit(self, 0, new_children_count)

        # update status
        self._set_status(TreeNodeStatus.Populated)


class TreeModel(QtCore.QAbstractItemModel):

    def __init__(self, root_node: TreeNode):
        super().__init__()

        # root node == data model
        self._root_node = root_node
        self._root_node.status_changed.connect(self._on_node_status_changed)
        self._root_node.before_children_added.connect(self._before_children_added)
        self._root_node.children_added.connect(self._on_children_added)
        self._root_node.before_children_removed.connect(self._before_children_removed)
        self._root_node.children_removed.connect(self._on_children_removed)

    def index(self, row: int, column: int, parent=QModelIndex(), *args, **kwargs) -> QModelIndex:
        # discard non-existent indices: check for row/column for given parent inside
        if not self.hasIndex(row, column, parent):
            return QModelIndex()

        # get parent node by index
        if parent is None or not parent.isValid():
            parent_node: TreeNode = self._root_node
        else:
            parent_node: TreeNode = parent.internalPointer()

        # if has child with given row
        if row < len(parent_node.children()):
            # create index with node as internalPointer
            return self.createIndex(row, column, parent_node.children()[row])

        return QModelIndex()

    def parent(self, index: QModelIndex = None) -> QModelIndex:
        # invalid index => root node
        if not index.isValid():
            return QModelIndex()

        node: TreeNode = index.internalPointer()
        parent_node: TreeNode = node.parent()

        # if parent is root node, return invalid index
        if parent_node is self._root_node:
            return QModelIndex()

        # get row of parent node; parent_node is not root, must have it's own parent
        grandparent_node = parent_node.parent()
        parent_row = grandparent_node.children().index(parent_node)

        # create index with node as internalPointer
        return self.createIndex(parent_row, 0, parent_node)

    def hasChildren(self, parent=QModelIndex(),  *args, **kwargs) -> bool:
        # can we expand node? if we can we have a triangle to the left of the node

        parent_node = self._node_from_index(parent)

        # children loaded - look at the number
        if parent_node.status == TreeNodeStatus.Populated:
            return len(parent_node.children()) > 0
        # error - no children, can't expand
        elif parent_node.status == TreeNodeStatus.Error:
            return False
        # not loaded/loading - assume they are
        else:
            return True

    def canFetchMore(self, parent: QModelIndex) -> bool:
        # can we get more data (child nodes) for parent?
        # print('canFetchMore!', self._node_from_index(parent).name)
        return self._can_fetch_more(parent)

    def _can_fetch_more(self, parent: QModelIndex) -> bool:
        parent_node = self._node_from_index(parent)

        # children are not loaded/loading - assume they are
        if parent_node.status == TreeNodeStatus.NotPopulated:
            return True
        # in other cases - can not get more child nodes
        elif parent_node.status in [TreeNodeStatus.Populating,
                                    TreeNodeStatus.Populated,
                                    TreeNodeStatus.Error]:
            return False
        assert False

    def fetchMore(self, parent: QModelIndex) -> None:
        # get more data (child nodes) for parent
        print('!FetchMore', self._node_from_index(parent).name)

        if not self._can_fetch_more(parent):
            return

        parent_node = self._node_from_index(parent)

        if parent_node.status != TreeNodeStatus.Populating:
            parent_node.populate()

    def rowCount(self, parent=QModelIndex(), *args, **kwargs):
        parent_node = self._node_from_index(parent)
        return len(parent_node.children())

    def columnCount(self, parent=None, *args, **kwargs):
        return 1

    def _node_from_index(self, index: Optional[QModelIndex]) -> TreeNode:
        # invalid index - root node
        if index is None or not index.isValid():
            return self._root_node
        else:
            return index.internalPointer()

    def _index_from_node(self, node: TreeNode) -> Optional[QModelIndex]:
        # root node - invalid index
        if node is self._root_node:
            return QModelIndex()

        # according to the principle from index method
        parent_node = node.parent()
        row = parent_node.children().index(node)
        return self.createIndex(row, 0, node)

    def data(self, index, role=None):

        node = self._node_from_index(index)

        if role == Qt.DisplayRole:
            return node.name

        # get nodes by UserRole
        elif role == Qt.UserRole:
            return node

        elif role == Qt.DecorationRole:
            pass

    def _on_node_status_changed(self, node: TreeNode):
        index = self._index_from_node(node)

        if index is not None:
            # notify about changes - icon, tooltip
            self.dataChanged.emit(index, index, [Qt.DecorationRole, Qt.ToolTipRole])

    def _before_children_removed(self, parent_node: TreeNode, pos: int, count: int):
        parent_index = self._index_from_node(parent_node)

        if parent_index is not None:
            self.beginRemoveRows(parent_index, pos, pos + count - 1)

    def _on_children_removed(self, parent_node: TreeNode, pos: int, count: int):
        self.endRemoveRows()

    def _before_children_added(self, parent_node: TreeNode, pos: int, count: int):
        parent_index = self._index_from_node(parent_node)

        if parent_index is not None:
            self.beginInsertRows(parent_index, pos, pos + count - 1)
            print('!beginInsertRows', parent_node.name)

    def _on_children_added(self, parent_node: TreeNode, pos: int, count: int):
        self.endInsertRows()
        print('!endInsertRows', parent_node.name)


class TreeView(QTreeView):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        self._menu = QMenu(self)

        # reload child nodes
        self._reload_act = self._menu.addAction('Reload')
        self._reload_act.triggered.connect(self._on_reload)

    def mouseReleaseEvent(self, event):
        """ Call context menu on right click button release """
        super().mouseReleaseEvent(event)
        if event.button() == Qt.MouseButton.RightButton:
            index = self.indexAt(event.pos())
            # above nodes only
            if index.isValid():
                self._menu.popup(self.viewport().mapToGlobal(event.pos()))

    def _on_reload(self):
        index = self.currentIndex()
        node = index.data(role=Qt.UserRole)
        if node.status != TreeNodeStatus.Populating:
            node.populate()


class ClientWindow(QMainWindow):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self._setup_ui()

        root_node = TreeNode('root', None)
        model = TreeModel(root_node)
        # proxy = QtCore.QSortFilterProxyModel()
        # proxy.setSourceModel(model)
        # FixMe crash on expanding any node if we put source model here
        self._view.setModel(model)

    def _setup_ui(self):
        self._view = TreeView()
        self._view.setSortingEnabled(True)

        central_wdg = self._view
        central_vlt = QVBoxLayout()
        central_wdg.setLayout(central_vlt)
        self.setCentralWidget(central_wdg)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication([])
    main_window = ClientWindow()
    main_window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec())
```

Comment: The object structure is quite complex, but I understand its requirements. There's probably something going wrong with the timing of signal emission and their processing, probably related with the fact that item views use a *delayed* laying out for items (I recommend you to patiently study the Qt sources for that). From a first glance, it seems that the source of the problem might be within `fetchMore()`, and a possible workaround could be to just delay the `populate` function: instead of directly calling it, try with `QTimer.singleShot(0, parent_node.populate)`, which seems to "fix" the issue.

Comment: Note that the above is not "the" solution, just a temporary workaround, since the `QTimer.singleShot()` gives no control over repeated calls. A *better* (but still not completely valid) solution would be to create a persistent singleShot QTimer object for each node, using a 0 interval and connected to the `self.populate` function, then call another function in `fetchMore()` that would eventually start the timer **if** the status flag is not `Populated`. Still, some further debugging is needed, and I also suggest you to add some more `print` here and there (before and after calling functions).

Comment: Btw, sorry for my original comment, I misread your question, believing that you used a blocking function to delay calls: your code is quite extensive, and I didn't read/test it in full. For future reference, though, remember to try to keep examples in single code blocks, so that it will be easier for us to test and *reproduce* the problem: we need to focus on the problem, without being distracted by trying to reproduce it, copying separate snippets and fixing namespaces or references; unless your problem is related to imports and relative paths, using different files for examples is pointless.

Comment: Finally, sorry for not writing an answer, but I don't like to post answers unless I'm sure about their results, and I'm not completely sure of what I wrote above for your case. So, please take your time to test my suggestions and add comments (or [edit] your question) in order to provide more insights based on your *actual* case and results. Then, eventually, I'll write a proper answer, as long as it fits the case and actually solves it.

Comment: You're right, single shot timer fixes the problem. Based on this idea I added the signal with QueuedConnection to avoid direct call of `populate` and it works too. Still I used a single shot timer to imitate request delay. This a bit more elegant, i have no need to call `stop`.

Will looking for docs about delayed laying out for items. Sorry for my english and thank you!

Comment: There's no documentation about the layout of items or its delay: those aspects are part of the internal implementation and don't normally need to be in the docs; you can only find it by studying the sources, starting with those related to QAbstractItemView and QTreeView. I suggest you to use the [KDAB code browser](codebrowser.dev), which provides a powerful interface with tooltips and references to functions and objects. If you're not familiar with C++, don't be scared: it takes some time to get used to it, but its syntax is quite similar to Python, and Qt code is generally well written.

Comment: Note that since your solution slightly diverts from my suggestion, you should provide your own answer, including a [mre] (or at least, the parts that have changed) and some insight about the reasons of the modifications and their results.

Comment: I consider my 'solution' from UPD 1 more as a workaround. Since my question was more about the reasons of crash I will leave it in UPD. I will write an answer if I finally figure out the delayed laying out of items mechnism.

Comment: Oh, understood about docs. Thanks for your advices on sources.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was in TreeNode._populate method. We need to emit `before_children_removed` signal only when `count > 0`. Like this.

```
if old_children_count > 0:
            self.before_children_removed.emit(self, 0, old_children_count)
```

Same for `children_removed` signal.

```
if old_children_count > 0:
            self.children_removed.emit(self, 0, old_children_count)
```

So no more need for `_populate_request` signal and other workarounds.

### Explanation

It was a mistake to send `before_children_removed` signal when `old_children_count == 0`. This situation arose during the first `populate` call for the node.

In that case I had a `TreeModel._before_children_removed` call with `pos=0` and `count=0`, `TreeModel.beginRemoveRows` with `first=0` and `last=-1` inside. These values triggers `Q_ASSERT(last >= first);` in Qt source code and caused another subsequent errors and finally crash.

```
void QAbstractItemModel::beginRemoveRows(const QModelIndex &parent, int first, int last)
{
    Q_ASSERT(first >= 0);
    Q_ASSERT(last >= first);
    Q_ASSERT(last < rowCount(parent));
    Q_D(QAbstractItemModel);
    d->changes.push(QAbstractItemModelPrivate::Change(parent, first, last));
    emit rowsAboutToBeRemoved(parent, first, last, QPrivateSignal());
    d->rowsAboutToBeRemoved(parent, first, last);
}
```

Curious that this `Q_ASSERT` does not lead to app crash when using release Qt DLLs. Release DLLs with debug symbols shows only another subsequent errors, consequences. The real reason we can see only with debug Qt DLLs.